# How to replace text in file - conditions and arithmetic required

Tags: scripting, replace, text, arithmetic

I need a script to change content in some text files.  This a bit beyond my limited bash skills.  Maybe perl or python would be a better approach, I have no experience with either of these.

I have a large number of text files created from a report.  Some of these files contain an error where I need to replace a money value that is incorrectly listed as $0.00.  The new value must be double the amount of another value reported in the same file.

The filenames of the files that need amending all contain the word 'Summary'.  If 'Summary' is not in the filename, then the file should be ignored.

The files include a line 'Category X cost price: $0.00,', where X is a number.  Only if X is 0 (zero) the $0.00 must be replaced, any other value for X then the file should be ignored.  I would like to identify this by checking for the presence of string 'Category 0 cost price: $0.00,'.

Other lines starting with 'Category' are unimportant here and should be ignored (e.g 'Category X sale price: $0.00,', others also exist).

Only 'Category X cost price: $0.00,' is important here.  The value in this line is always $0.00 and needs to be amended only if X is zero.

The new value is the 'Cost' value multiplied by 2.

The lines of interest are not fixed to a particular line number, unlike the examples below.  'Cost' may not always be on the second line, 'Category X cost price' may not always be on the fourth line.

Examples :

file : 1234 Summary.text

```
Some data
Cost: $15.73
Line of data
Category 0 cost price: $0.00,
Category 0 sale price: $0.00,
Category 4 list price: $44.95,
More data
```

The 'Category X cost price' is zero so price needs to change to ($15.73 * 2) $31.46 (NOTE the , must remain at the end of the amended line)

amended file : 1234 Summary.text

```
Some data
Cost: $15.73
Line of data
Category 0 cost price: $31.46,
Category 0 sale price: $0.00,
Category 4 list price: $44.95,
More data
```

---

file : 2468 Summary.text

```
Some data
Cost: $1.32
Line of data
Category 12 cost price: $0.00,
Category 5 sale price: $4.75,
Category 0 list price: $4.75,
More data
```

'Category X cost price' is not zero, ignore this file as no change is required.

---

To summarise, loop through filenames containing word 'Summary', if string 'Category 0 price: $0.00,' is present, then replace '0.00' with double the value in line 'Cost: $X.XX'.  Otherwise ignore the file.

I also need a list of the files that are amended.  Adding the filename to a separate text file would be great.

Comment: "_I need a script to change content in some text files._" we are not a script writing service

Comment: Thanks, I was requesting help.  Any tips, or links to useful articles or commands, etc that would be helpful to me would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `awk` ([suggested tutorial](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)) and use `$` as field separator. That way you may check for field 1 as `Cost: ` to get the value or `Category 0 cost price: ` for when it needs replacement. Do not forget to add the comma then. .... Once you tried to figure this out, be welcome to ask more specific questions where you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks FelixNJ, I'll check that out and will update.

Answer (score 0):

This [TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr) solution works for me.

I used the `#;` comment notation to disable the `(rename-path ...)` expression which renames each temp file back to the original name; remove the `#;` notation to activate the in-place replacement if what is in the `.tmp` files looks good. An improvement would be to remove the `.tmp` file instead if there is no change.

```
(each ((file (glob "*Summary.txt")))
  (let ((cost 0.0))
    (flow
      (file-get-lines file)
      (mapcar (do match-case @1
                (`Cost: $@val`
                  (set cost (flo-str val))
                  @1)
                ("Category 0 cost price: $0.00,"
                  (pic "Category 0 cost price $#.##," (* 2 cost)))
                (@else @1)))
      (file-put-lines `@file.tmp`))
    #;(rename-path `@file.tmp` file)))
```